# Nameserver returns different records on different machines

Tags: dns, centos, nameservers, dig

I'm facing with this strange DNS issue on one of the CentOS boxes, in which the authoritative NS returns outdated records, which results in failure in the resolution.

The domain I'm trying to resolve is *chengyu.ga*.

Let's call the problematic CentOS box **A** and a normal CentOS box **B**.

Here is the dig trace when running on **B**, which returns correct answers:

```
$ dig chengyu.ga +trace +additional

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-9.P2.el7 <<>> chengyu.ga +trace +additional
;; global options: +cmd
.                       518400  IN      NS      F.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      G.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      H.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      I.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      J.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      K.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      L.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      M.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      A.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      B.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      C.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      D.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
.                       518400  IN      NS      E.ROOT-SERVERS.NET.
;; Received 239 bytes from 172.31.0.2#53(172.31.0.2) in 0 ms

ga.                     172800  IN      NS      a.ns.ga.
ga.                     172800  IN      NS      b.ns.ga.
ga.                     172800  IN      NS      c.ns.ga.
ga.                     172800  IN      NS      d.ns.ga.
ga.                     86400   IN      NSEC    gal. NS RRSIG NSEC
ga.                     86400   IN      RRSIG   NSEC 8 1 86400 20200327050000 20200314040000 33853 . AUOV4PSeXQZ+PpcrnlNQIxmP1vnMcTe77+bQop06CAx1Q4oPMm+ujQY3 AMnp+ex8onrv
1VpJgaENd4gyf6bgOkYCNcy2hY/DpXyQ1UY/TLBZigkO Q+xtDwVcXnw/BvP+KpDeEj0KcMSh8qqRRkhVH77KPOEVgmQzyuUZ12GH sc9mmcwxT/Ugl+qG60ib7C3jFi8VYGsMNUk+p2RfDw5MPRPfFGZxEyNH XdmW7ABYm62
QdI1oAVPND9UjVkV/aw59Yq55cwrFqcQt+2aM10yrssII nx0o5NX3zqhMt2gkwOnZrGBgIxD1QdJXMZtT7aPk3UgaAvFnOgOpg81Y HtdTFg==
a.ns.ga.                172800  IN      A       185.21.168.49
a.ns.ga.                172800  IN      AAAA    2a04:1b00:c::1
b.ns.ga.                172800  IN      A       185.21.169.49
b.ns.ga.                172800  IN      AAAA    2a04:1b00:d::1
c.ns.ga.                172800  IN      A       185.21.170.49
c.ns.ga.                172800  IN      AAAA    2a04:1b00:e::1
d.ns.ga.                172800  IN      A       185.21.171.49
d.ns.ga.                172800  IN      AAAA    2a04:1b00:f::1
;; Received 594 bytes from 192.5.5.241#53(F.ROOT-SERVERS.NET) in 3 ms

chengyu.ga.             300     IN      NS      ns-1096.awsdns-09.org.
chengyu.ga.             300     IN      NS      ns-58.awsdns-07.com.
chengyu.ga.             300     IN      NS      ns-720.awsdns-26.net.
chengyu.ga.             300     IN      NS      ns-1829.awsdns-36.co.uk.
;; Received 178 bytes from 185.21.171.49#53(d.ns.ga) in 186 ms

chengyu.ga.             60      IN      A       3.112.158.242
chengyu.ga.             60      IN      A       52.196.4.107
chengyu.ga.             60      IN      A       13.114.167.91
chengyu.ga.             172800  IN      NS      ns-1096.awsdns-09.org.
chengyu.ga.             172800  IN      NS      ns-1829.awsdns-36.co.uk.
chengyu.ga.             172800  IN      NS      ns-58.awsdns-07.com.
chengyu.ga.             172800  IN      NS      ns-720.awsdns-26.net.
;; Received 226 bytes from 205.251.199.37#53(ns-1829.awsdns-36.co.uk) in 3 ms
```

And results from **A**:

```
$ dig chengyu.ga +trace +additional

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.el8 <<>> chengyu.ga +trace +additional
;; global options: +cmd
.           259199  IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           259199  IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           259199  IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
.           259199  IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           259199  IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           259199  IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           259199  IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           259199  IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           259199  IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           259199  IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
.           259199  IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           259199  IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           259199  IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
.           259199  IN  RRSIG   NS 8 0 518400 20200326050000 20200313040000 33853 . Qm1Ie0FEwyqy+PCVypAz7PuwJ4aFaQAjU2om+IRPQb/eQ2xjAwDm0YnW vws6lzDe5KKTkQYmSYmPyJ+ccoCk6zqvVVFzMjNQk5mgIpLdxvxLibkk 0hW5MFtY4fdFKmTS14RuqfEXVkEaYIph/Hvyh7Mw/5hKSttwMbJTELfx 8rBEQwVVFYcdazc2oko0UvnBSlnoYbpvlVR7QcrhJ7fAEQfzyy9SsR0Z jWn2G+OdwSfJgN1f7BXftC055yEnCWfG+qJNWrt+QofNolgQTbQDOY3t 3m9ITkBJvvPSUKH7mIIXHYMM3wbO6PenkY9VaPTYW+XkAxJvR+/r+UvE iEpSQw==
;; Received 525 bytes from 169.254.169.254#53(169.254.169.254) in 2 ms

ga.         172800  IN  NS  a.ns.ga.
ga.         172800  IN  NS  b.ns.ga.
ga.         172800  IN  NS  c.ns.ga.
ga.         172800  IN  NS  d.ns.ga.
ga.         86400   IN  NSEC    gal. NS RRSIG NSEC
ga.         86400   IN  RRSIG   NSEC 8 1 86400 20200327050000 20200314040000 33853 . AUOV4PSeXQZ+PpcrnlNQIxmP1vnMcTe77+bQop06CAx1Q4oPMm+ujQY3 AMnp+ex8onrv1VpJgaENd4gyf6bgOkYCNcy2hY/DpXyQ1UY/TLBZigkO Q+xtDwVcXnw/BvP+KpDeEj0KcMSh8qqRRkhVH77KPOEVgmQzyuUZ12GH sc9mmcwxT/Ugl+qG60ib7C3jFi8VYGsMNUk+p2RfDw5MPRPfFGZxEyNH XdmW7ABYm62QdI1oAVPND9UjVkV/aw59Yq55cwrFqcQt+2aM10yrssII nx0o5NX3zqhMt2gkwOnZrGBgIxD1QdJXMZtT7aPk3UgaAvFnOgOpg81Y HtdTFg==
a.ns.ga.        172800  IN  A   185.21.168.49
b.ns.ga.        172800  IN  A   185.21.169.49
c.ns.ga.        172800  IN  A   185.21.170.49
d.ns.ga.        172800  IN  A   185.21.171.49
a.ns.ga.        172800  IN  AAAA    2a04:1b00:c::1
b.ns.ga.        172800  IN  AAAA    2a04:1b00:d::1
c.ns.ga.        172800  IN  AAAA    2a04:1b00:e::1
d.ns.ga.        172800  IN  AAAA    2a04:1b00:f::1
;; Received 594 bytes from 198.41.0.4#53(a.root-servers.net) in 2 ms

chengyu.ga.     300 IN  NS  ns01.freenom.com.
chengyu.ga.     300 IN  NS  ns02.freenom.com.
chengyu.ga.     300 IN  NS  ns03.freenom.com.
chengyu.ga.     300 IN  NS  ns04.freenom.com.
;; Received 126 bytes from 185.21.168.49#53(a.ns.ga) in 2 ms

;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
[guanshan@instance-2 ~]$ dig @185.21.171.49 chengyu.ga +trace +additional

; <<>> DiG 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.el8 <<>> @185.21.171.49 chengyu.ga +trace +additional
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Received 28 bytes from 185.21.171.49#53(185.21.171.49) in 2 ms
```

FYI, the `.freenom.com.` NS servers have been changed to `awsdns` server a couple of days back. As you can see, the results returned by `a.ns.ga` are outdated.

My question is, what could cause this kind of behavior?

Comment: Do you have NSCD running ?

Comment: @tomgalpin That was the first thing I checked. And nope. BTW, looks like the resolution finally correct itself mysteriously. Still, not quite sure what had happened.